# Remove Multiple Elements in a Python List Once

Tags: list, python-3.6, python-3.5, python-3.4, remove-method

(Using Python 3)

Given this list named numList: [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4].
I want to remove exactly one instance of “1” and “3” from numList.
In other words, I want a function that will turn numList into: [1,2,2,3,3,4].
What function will let me remove an X number of elements from a Python list once per element I want to remove?
(The elements I want to remove are guaranteed to exist in the list)

For the sake of clarity, I will give more examples:

[1,2,3,3,4]
Remove 2 and 3
[1,3,4]

[3,3,3]
Remove 3
[3,3]

[1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4]
Remove 2, 3 and 4
[1,1,2,4,4,4]

I’ve tried doing this:

numList=[1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4]

remList = [2,3,4]

for x in remList:

```
 numList.remove(x)
```

This turns numList to [1,2,3,4,4] which is what I want. However, this has a complexity of:

O((len(numList))^(len(remList)))

This is a problem because remList and numList can have a length of 10^5. The program will take a long time to run. Is there a built-in function that does what I want faster?

Also, I would prefer the optimum function which can do this job in terms of space and time because the program needs to run in less than a second and the size of the list is large.

Comment: `for i in (2, 3): numList.remove(i)`

Comment: I added my attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach:

```
for x in rem_list:
    num_list.remove(x)
```

is intuitative and unless the lists are going to be very large I might do that because it is easy to read.

One alternative would be:

```
result = []
for x in num_list:
    if x in rem_list:
        rem_list.remove(x)
    else:
        result.append(x)
```

This would be O(len(rem_list) ^ len(num_list)) and faster than the first solution if len(rem_list) < len(num_list).

If rem_list was guaranteed to not contain any duplicates (as per your examples) you could use a set instead and the complexity would be O(len(num_list)).

Comment: It’s still O(n^n) complexity though. Both lists have the same length in the worst cases (which is 10^5)